# Apache restarting itself and website is extremely slow

Tags: apache, security, webserver, intrusion-detection

I have a problem with Apache web server restarting itself, my site is extremely slow on admin panel and FTP and I suspect my site might have been hacked.

What are the best ways to see if my site was hacked and to find out who it was? And what best procedures can I take to make sure its safe and doesn't happen again?

Comment: What OS are you running? Have you checked the access logs? How much memory is the apache process running? Any more information?

Comment: Where can I find access logs?

Comment: Your access logs will be defined in your apache config